# Artifacts when drawing primitives with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on some code involving use of the pygame library to draw a circle to a surface. The code to draw the circle looks something like the following:

```
  surf = pygame.Surface((2000,2000))
  pygame.draw.circle(surf, 
                     pygame.Color("white"),
                     (1000,1000),
                     508,
                     50)
```

The problem is that the resulting circle has artifacts
[image: Circle with artifacts]

Is there anyway to draw a circle like this without getting these artifacts?

Comment: Most probably because the circle isn't Anti-aliased.

Comment: Have a complete example that shows this?

Comment: @ChasingDeath: The dots you see on the circle are either result of dithering or rendering library doesn't know how to draw circle properly (and tries to plot it by rotating line primitive or something like that). Either scenario has nothing to do with antialiasing.

Comment: Looks like a moiré pattern to me.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Then it is fault of pygame.draw. If you see moire pattern it happened because someone didn't know how to draw circle properly. Perhaps library internally draw 50 circles in sequence, increasing radius by one. Of course that's not going to work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you see is most likely a problem with pygame.draw.circle implementation. Most likely pygame developer foolishly assumed that you can draw thick circle by drawing several circles in sequence, increasing radius by one for every circle. That's not going to work in practice and you'll get moire pattern like the one you see. Try increasing circle line thickness by 100 or 200 and see what happens. If it gets worse,  then it is `pygame.draw.circle`'s fault.

A solution would be to provide your own circle rendering routine. This can be certainly be done, but for optimum performance it makes sense to do it in C/C++ extension module for pygame OR using OpenGL (with or without fragment shaders).

To get a perfect circle for every scanline you'll have to calculate start and end of filled area for every scanline. It might be possible to do this in python with tolerable performance by using pygame.draw.line to draw individual scanlines.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer.  As soon as you change the circle width to 2 in my code below, the first crack starts to appear, if you look closely.`pygame.draw.circle(screen, 
                         pygame.Color("white"),
                         (1000,1000),
                         508,
                         2)`

Comment: This is correct, and is [documented in pygame's FAQ](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Why%20does%20drawing%20thick%20circles%20or%20arcs%20give).  According to the FAQ answer, you can use the SDL_gfx package included with pygame (from 1.9.0 onward), which contains a filled-elipse draw function, which you can use to draw two concentric circles.

Answer (score 2):

This bug is mentioned in the comments for the circle and arc methods.  There's one workaround in the comments of the [draw.circle documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle).  This is adapted from that workaround:

```
def draw_outlined_circle(surf, color, origin, radius, thickness):
    width = radius * 2 + thickness * 2
    background = (0, 0, 0, 0)
    circle = pygame.Surface((width, width)).convert_alpha()
    rect = circle.get_rect()
    circle.fill(background)
    pygame.draw.circle(circle, color, rect.center, radius)
    pygame.draw.circle(circle, background, rect.center, radius - thickness)
    surf.blit(circle, (origin[0] - (rect.w / 2), origin[1] - (rect.w / 2)))
```

This method uses an extra `Surface` and draws two circles: a smaller circle inside of a larger one to achieve the same effect.  The smaller circle's fill color has an alpha of 0, so the full circle's center appears transparent.

EDIT: From the above comment, I see the behavior is mentioned in the pygame FAQ as well.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue, and it will be in the next release of pygame (1.9.4). How do you draw circles like that without artifacts? Use the newer version of pygame.

Answer (score 0):

This might have happened with a problem on how pygame.draw.circle is implementing.
You can try the arcade library for better performance. Also, the arcade library is very easy to use while I find pygame quite complicated.